# Stop Saxon from returning XML declaration encoding attribute

Tags: java, xquery, saxon

I am running Saxon from the command line

```
java -cp Saxon net.sf.saxon.Query some.xquery
```

It runs and returns string data.

However, it als includes the following:

```
<?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“utf-8”?>
```

What option or parameter is required in xquery or java call to prevent this from being part of the output?

Comment: Depending on your needs, maybe the `method` or `omit-xml-declaration` [serialization params](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensions/output-extras/).

Comment: `java -cp Saxon net.sf.saxon.Query some.xquery !omit-xml-declaration=yes` (and escape the `!` using `\!`, if using Bash).

Comment: @andrewjames Never mind, ! saxon specific

Comment: @PaulM - Search on "exclamation point" on this page: https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xquery/commandline.html It's all in the docs ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If it's returning string data then you probably don't want `&` and `<` to be escaped, so you should be running with method=text. You can specify that either within the query itself (`declare option output:method "text"`); , or on the command line (`!method=text`).